# SQLDelight with KMM and R8

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, android-r8, sqldelight

I have a KMM project with SQLDelight and try to use R8 but it crashes (NullPointerException) and the reason (as far as I could narrow it down) is that the database initialisation fails. Are there any known rules for SQLDelight?

Comment: You should post much more context. The error, stack trace, config code, etc.